# How to create an ASP.NET Core Authorization Policy that contains 2x logic rules?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

Given an API route that retrieves a users data from a database:

```
/users/{userId}  // e.g.  /users/1
```

I'm trying to add some security logic in place to make sure that when **at least one** following rules are checked, some data will be returned when:

- Auth'd user is accessing their own record. e.g. Auth'd userId == 1, /users/1
- Auth'd user has the claim `CanAccessAnyUser`

To do this in a simple ASP.NET Core app, I was going to leverage `Policy` based Authorization.

Notice how I said "**at least one** of those rules? That's the bit I'm stuck with.

Currently I've figured out that I can do the first rule with [Resource Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

The second rule can be done using a simple `.RequireClaims` policy check.

But I'm not sure how to set them both up in startup.cs? Here's some code to explain.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("pewpew", policy => ??? );

    // This is logical 'AND' logic checks. Not a logic 'OR' check :(
    options.AddPolicy("CanAccessAUser", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new UserIdRequirement())
              .RequiresClaim("CanAccessAnyUser");
}


public class CanAccessAUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SameUserIdRequirement, string>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   SameUserIdRequirement requirement,
                                                   string resource)
    {
        if (context.User != null &&
            context.User.UserId().Equals(resource, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class SameUserIdRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

and to use this in some code... (this is in a controller or (in this example) a Mediatr's Handler):

```
public async Task<Response> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Security check.
    var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
        request.ClaimsPrincipal,
        request.UserId,
        "CanAccessAnyUser");

    ....
}
```

References:

- Andrew Lock's blog with [respect to Authorization](https://andrewlock.net/custom-authorisation-policies-and-requirements-in-asp-net-core/).
- MS Docs

Answer (score 0):

The policy based authorisation sees these are two different requirements. A `UserIdRequirement` and a `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement`.

Looking through the example in the Policy base authorisation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for the OR logic, you need to have one requirement. You can then have multiple handlers for the same requirement or add all the logic to one handler.

The example in the blog post also has one requirement a `AssesrtionRequirement`.

This is most probably not what you were looking for though.

Alternatively, check the `AuthorizationResult.Fail.FailedRequirements` to see if all requirements have failed.

Alternatively you can change your handler to authorise on each requirement. You will need to inject `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider` into the handler and then do something like this:

```
AuthorizationPolicy authorisationPolicy = _authorizationPolicyProvider.GetPol.GetPolicyAsync(policy);
foreach (IAuthorizationRequirement authorisationPolicyRequirement in authorisationPolicy.Requirements)
        {
            var result _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(principal, userId, authorisationPolicyRequirement);
            if (result.Succeeded) return true;
        }
```